# Java returning numbers below the avg

Tags: java, arrays

ne of my projects assigned was to create an array for 10 variables which the user inputs and to have the program output the average of the input number as well as listing the numbers below the average. I am able to obtain the average without an issue but my code to return the numbers below the average seems to not be doing the job. For example if I input into the array the values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] the average outputs as 5.5 (which is good) but the output I want from BelowAverage is 1,2,3,4,5 can anyone help me?

```
public static double BelowAverage(ArrayList<Double> Averages) {
    int i, aveless = 0; double avg = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < Averages.size(); i++) 
        avg = Averages.get(i);
    avg /= Averages.size();
    for(i = 0; i < Averages.size(); i++) 
        if(Averages.size() < avg) 
            aveless++;
    return aveless;
}
```

Comment: What does `seems to not be doing the job` mean? Your `BelowAverage` method seems to be over thought. Just get the average from `CalculateAverages`, iterate through  `Averages` in `BelowAverage` and print any item in the ArrayList which is less than the average.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that your parameter names don't make sense. You're taking in an ArrayList of doubles called `Averages` which you are taking the average of??

Comment: You're supposed to list the numbers that are below average, but you have no method taking an input list, an input (pre-computed average), and returning the requested list of below-average numbers. Start by learning the Java naming conventions, and think about the signatures and return types of your methods. Split the problem in simple parts, implemented as methods, with documented arguments and return types. Then fill in the method implementations. Example: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/a642463f7ffd177d99f351655dfa79eb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and you want a list with all the numbers below the average, you should change the return value and the code, like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> BelowAverage(ArrayList<Double> Averages) {
    // You already have a method for calculating the average, so use it
    double avg = CalculateAverages(Averages);
    ArrayList<Double> aveless = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < Averages.size(); i++){
        double number = Averages.get(i);
        if(number < avg){
            aveless.add(number);
        }
    }
    return aveless;
}
```

Comment: Whenever I run this code upon inputting the numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] the average is returned correctly as 5.5, but the value returned for the numbers that are less than the average comes back as 5 as opposed to the wanted output of 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 which is the list of all the numbers less than 5.5.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. I didn't have Java to test the code, so it wasn't working properly. But good to know you figured it out. You're welcome

Answer (score 2):

1. No need to use wrappers, you could use `double` instead of `Double`.
2. Your variable naming is weird, why do you have an `ArrayList` of averages instead of numbers?
3. Follow Java [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

   - `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`
   - `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`
   - `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`
   - `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`

   and use them consistently
4. You already have a method that calculates the average, why not use it?

So, for example, your code might look like this (with slight modifications):

```
public static int belowAverage(List<Double> numbers) {
    double avg = calculateAverages(numbers); //Go, get the average using the method you already have
    int aveless = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        if (numbers.get(i) < avg) { //Instead of comparing the numbers array size, compare the number against the average.
            aveless++;
        }
    }
    return aveless;
}
```

I added opening and closing curly braces for the `for` loop as I think it's easier to read that way.

I also changed the return type to `int` instead of `double` on this method as you only want to count, so, decimal point is not needed and moved the `System.out.println()` call inside the `calculateAverage()` method to the `main` method.

I also changed the parameter type to the interface one (from `ArrayList` to `List`)

Comment: I apologize for not using the correct Java Naming Convention, my professor has not covered this topic at all. Its an intro to java course and we are technically still working on what is a string, what is an int etc, I just wanted to get ahead and do the programs to not have to worry about them later. As far as my course is concerned, my professor just wants "meaningful" names for classes, variables, and methods so that he understands their purpose. I believe the actual naming conventions are covered next semester in 202.

Comment: @BrianCheda anyway if you want to get ahead, why not learn that straight away and make it easier to read for you, us, and your professor? They are not hard to learn actually...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to bee on this line:

```
if(Averages.size() < avg) aveless++;
```

You should be checking `Averages.get(i) < avg` instead, otherwise what is the point of looping?

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of 'numbers' which have less value than the average, you should compare each element inside that array with the average, not with the size of the array. Try it as follows:

```
public static double BelowAverage(ArrayList<Double> Averages) {
    int i, aveless = 0; double avg = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < Averages.size(); i++) 
        avg = Averages.get(i);
    avg /= Averages.size();
    for(Double a : Averages) 
        if(a < avg) aveless++;
    return aveless;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. Let's go through them one at a time.

**First problem:**

```
for(i = 0; i < Averages.size(); i++) 
    avg = Averages.get(i); //this line
avg /= Averages.size();
```

You are simply reassigning the value of `avg` in the loop. What you want to do is to keep adding values to it. Replace `=` with `+=` to get `avg += Averages.get(i);`.

**Second problem:**

```
for(i = 0; i < Averages.size(); i++) 
    if(Averages.size() < avg) 
        aveless++;
```

Here you are checking whether `avg` is larger than the **size of the list** which is not what you want to be doing. What you wonder is whether `avg` is larger than the values in the list. You need to replace `Averages.size()` with `Averages.get(i)`. This is a relatively easy mistake to spot because the loop is not really achieving anything right now, so look out for things like this.

**Edit:** There are a few other problems as well. `avg` should be a double and not an int, because ints cannot store decimal places and there is no guarantee that your average is a whole number, so you will get a rounding error. Furthermore, your method should return an int instead of a double because *"the number of values below average"* is always an integer.